# Spring 4 Rest problems

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to create a spring mvc rest app using spring 4 with the added restcontroller feature but i get an error inside the restcontrollerclass which i cant solve.

The error i get is this

I cannot import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController; to my restcontroller class it's marked with a red line underneath. I have got all the correct jars

Restcontroller

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

this is the line that is marked with a red line underneath
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
if i remove the annotaion @Restcontroller the error disapears
so how do i import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; without      getting an error

[code] 
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/testrest")
public class RestController {

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(){
    return "hello";
}
}
[/code]

pom.xml
[code]



<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>se.molin</groupId>
<artifactId>blogga</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.29</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- projectNameTemplate>[artifactId]-[version]</projectNameTemplate -->
                <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


 </project>
[/code]
```

Comment: If you are just starting with Spring (and it seems that you are) I recommend going through Spring Guides, especially this one in your case: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: as per @MaciejWalkowiak its a good idea to review the tutorials, but don't do a straight copy as they focus on spring boot and hence use spring boot packages.

Answer (score 1):

Include this in your Pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And let me know how you go.

Comment: OP mentioned using Spring 4.

Comment: It would have worked either way, changed the version to the OPs spring framework variable to make it easier.

Comment: @RestController appeared in Spring 4.

Answer (score 0):

@RestController and your class name(RestController) are conflicting. You can't have the same name in as class. Change the name of your class file. it should work.